# Best way to optimize queries like this in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to lower the amount of queries that my django app is using, but I am a little confused on how to do it.

I would like to get a query set with one hit to the database and then filter items from that set.  I have tried a couple of things, but I always get queries for each set.

let's say I want to get all names from my DB, but also separate out the people just named Ted. Both the names and the ted set will be used in the template.

This will give me two sets, one with all names and one with Ted..  but also hits the database twice:

namelist = People.objects.all()

tedList = namelist.filter(name='ted')

Is there a way to filter the first set without hitting the data base again?

Comment: First, please indent your code four spaces.  Use the "101010" button.  Second, Django (and your databases) make extensive use of caches.  How do you know these queries are actually a performance problem?  Please provide some metrics to show that queries are slowing your application down.

Comment: I see two hits to the database, for something that I would think could take one hit.  That is what I am going off of.  Seems like common sense to me that one hit is better then two... but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tedList = [person for person in namelist if person.name == 'ted']
```

This will filter the initial `QueryList` on the client side.

Comment: There's a good chance that the DB query would be faster - databases are optimized for this sort of thing.

If someone were to actually test both methods, I'd be interested in seeing the results.